# How can I sort Quora answers by votes?

Tags: quora

The more upvoted an answer, the higher I desire it to appear. If possible, please include screenshots to illume where to click.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately you can not.**

At least not by default. There is no such option even if you are logged in.

As a workaround, you can [use one of the existing browser add-ons/plugins](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=how+to+sort+quora+answers+by+votes).
Just read, install, test and use one that best meets your needs.

Comment: Did you find the given solution wrong? If yes please comment and explain why. If not, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.